# How to set a Thunar window as the desktop in XFce?

Tags: xfce, thunar, kiosk

I want to setup one computer ask a kiosk for eBooks. I'd like any user to be able to see all available books right on the desktop. These can be clicked on and loaded in the PDF software.

Is there some way to place a fullscreen Thunar window, at a specific folder, as the desktop of XFce, so that the desktop has a folder showing all of the PDFs and can be navigated like a file manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Screenlets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenlets.

I was able to get it from the Linux Mint Software Manager. It's a program that places widgets, or screenlets, on the desktop. There are many of these screenlets, and they carry out certain functions, like system monitors. There's a particular screenlet I use called "Folder View." This screenlet will allow you to show a particular folder on your desktop, and the screenlet window can be resized.

[image: Screenlet Manager]